# How to chain prompts in teams-ai version 1.0.0 (MS Teams AI Bot app)?

Tags: typescript, azure-openai, teams-toolkit

In `@microsoft/teams-ai: ^0.1.0-preview.2` I used to use  `AI<ApplicationTurnState>.chain(context: TurnContext, state: ApplicationTurnState, prompt?: string | PromptTemplate, options?: Partial<AIOptions<ApplicationTurnState>>): Promise<...> Chains into another prompt and executes the plan that is returned.`.

Example:

```js
await app.ai.chain(context, state, 'generateSomeDocument');
```

However in the new `@microsoft/teams-ai: ^1.0.0` I cannot for the life of me find anything like that? The closest I've got is `ActionPlanner<TurnState<DefaultConversationState, DefaultUserState, DefaultTempState>>.completePrompt<string>(context: TurnContext, memory: Memory, prompt: string | PromptTemplate, validator?: PromptResponseValidator<string>): Promise<...> Completes a prompt using an optional validator.`

Example:

```js
const response = await planner.completePrompt(context, state, 'generateSomeDocument');
```

Naturally, `completePrompt` only returns DO/SAY JSON object, whereas `chain` method used to return expected result from a prompt chained onto the main prompt.

I've looked at all [the updated examples](https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai) and couldn't see anything in regards of this functionality?

I think I've managed to address all the other breaking changes but this one.

Comment: Hi @Donatas, not sure if you saw my comment at https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/discussions/1060#discussioncomment-8184835 - were you able to make progress on this?

Comment: Hi @Corina. Thank you for checking on me. Unfortunately I got stuck in my tracks on this particular issue because of this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/issues/1130. Not being able to produce meaningful prompts and responses meant I could not trust in my results, because I was simply getting DO/SAY commands back from the model. 

Despite that, I spent most of my time on this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/issues/1203 and it's still not resolved. 

Luckily, I could successfully demo AI Chat Bot capabilities without using SSO and using teams-ai preview version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Donatas. Sorry again that you have been having trouble with the library. I have escalated 1130 and will discuss with the team.

Comment: Thank you @Corina. I've started working on the new "chaining" concept. I must admit I'm a bit sceptical about the potential outcome here, but I will give it a try and will report the results and also what I'm after - which is basically chained prompts (not actions) with their own parameters - just like what `.chain()` used to allow to get done.

Comment: I've started a discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/discussions/1322 @Corina.